# (Artisan)Tinker not allowing me to access the profile table from the back end

Tags: php, html, eloquent, laravel-artisan, tinker

I have a User object that has a one-to-many relationship with a Profile object. I require the fields of the profile object in order to dynamically display it's variables on the web page. i.e. How many 'posts', Their 'description' etc. I ran into some problems regarding this retrieval a few days back. Naturally thinking it was a front-end error, I tried to add '@' tags - however, this seemed to only suppress the errors being flagged and not solve the problem. So I decided to check if when I used my edit profile page, and filled in fields and 'saved', if, on the back end, the fields were updated: that didn't work, and tinker flagged the attached error.

**Dynamic calling of user object attributes in html:**

```
<input  id="title"
type="text"
class="form-control
@error('title') is-invalid
@enderror"
name="title"
value="{{ old('title') ?? @$user->profile->title}}" required
autocomplete="title" autofocus>
```

**Update Function in ProfilesController**
(note that the 'profile' property is underlined as yellow)

```
public function update(User $user)
    {$data = request()->validate([

            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'url' => 'url',
            /*'image' => '', */


        ]);

       $user->profile->update($data);
       return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");

    }
```

Note that: the error flagged from this is
`'Call to a member function update() on null'`

**Profile method in the User class:**

```
 public function profile()
        {return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);}
```

**User method in the Profile class:**

```
 public function user()
    {return $this->belongsTo(User::class);}
```

**and Finally the error flagged when using Tinkers all();**

```
>>> Profile::all();
[!] Aliasing 'Profile' to 'App\Profile' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3080
     all: [],
   }
>>>
```

**Removed '@' tags error:**

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\Users\(PCNAMEfoo)\(PROJECTNAMEfoo)\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)
```

Edit 1 : I thought it would also be helpful to show what happens if I remove the '@' tags and navigate to the index page (under '*Dynamic calling of user object attributes in html*').

Edit 2: More information added.

This is my first post, so I hope it's been formatted correctly. Thanks for ANY level of input.

Comment: For the non-object error, the User doesn't have a profile. You'll want to check for a profile before you try to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. How would one go about doing such a check? would you direct me to some documentation I can look at?

Comment: There's no real documentation here. `old` allows a default value, so I'd probably throw a ternary in there. `old('title', $user->profile ? $user->profile->title : '')}}`

Comment: This solved the problem on the front, thank you very much. The back end problem still persists: It's not calling data directly from the user profile (`$user->profile`)  n(or) the title variable (`$user->profile->title`) , it's doing both checks and equating it to null (`:' '`)